# Why exist and how can i remove this blank space from the page [Img inside]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, css-position

[image: Example]

So, the thing is i re-check the code 3 times, i ask for help through several ways and i can't find the reason why that space exist, the problem is it musn't be there, here is the code of the three files implicated in the case

This is the 1/3, index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Clone Dinka</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chelsea+Market' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqwdinka.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mullet"></div>
    <header>
        <div id="BigSist"><img id="hermana" src="imago/upper_logo.png"/>​<p class="white">tel</p><p class="black">(+56 9) 65637350</p></div>

        <img id="logoc" src="imago/logo.png"/></img>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">​
                <p class="white" id="Tralala">DESPACHO DIRECTO A TU PUERTA</p>
                <span>Haz tu pedido / Cotiza</span>
            </div>
            <ul id="cont">
                <li id="than"><a href="main">INICIO</a></li>
                <li class="menuHead"><a href="#">PRODUCTOS</a>
                    <ul id="cont">
                        <li><a href="verduras">Verduras</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Frutas">Frutas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="MoteconHuesillo">Mote con Huesillo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ComoComprar">¿COMO COMPRAR?</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contacto">CONTACTO</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--"http://lorempixel.com/g/470/300"-->
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the 2/3, Style.css

```
/*---Estilos Generales---*/
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    clear:right;
}

body {
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family:arial;
    position:Absolute;
}
a {
    color:#bf2222;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
    color:#bf2222;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/*---Header---*/

header 
{
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:100%;
    height:9.5em;
    position:relative;
    border:15px 0 solid transparent;
    font: bold 30px/1.1em "Chelsea Market";
    position:relative;
}
.mullet
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:18.10em;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#778d00;
    opacity:0.25;
    z-index:0;
}
#BigSist > p {
    left:68.5%;
    margin-top:6.5%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    bottom:1.4em;
    font: bold 30px/1.1em "Chelsea Market";
}
.white {
color:#ffffff;
}

.black{
color:#380807;
}


header #hermana {
    right:30%;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

header #logoc {
    bottom:2.8em;
    display:inline-block; /**/
    position:relative;

}

/* header #logo p {
    font-family:sans-serif, helvetica, arial;
    font-size:4rem;
    font-weight:100;
    text-align:left;
    color:#FFFFFF; 
} */
header nav span:hover {
    background-color: #A91B17;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
    }
header nav span {
    text-align:center;
    width:220px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:55%;
    font-weight:400;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    right:8px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#778D00;
    border: 1px hidden #000000;
    border-radius:3px;
    position: relative;
    }
.container {
    width:650px;
    left:12.5%;s
    position: relative;
}
#Tralala{
    font-size:65%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
/*---Menu---*/

header nav {
    height:65px;
    width:65%;
    float:right;
    padding:10px 0px;
    /* position:absolute; 
    background:#360480;*/
    position:relative;
}

header nav ul {
    height:45%;

    position:relative;
    margin:0 12.5% 10px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block; 

    width:580px;
    right:2em;

    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 6px 6px 5px 2px; 
    -moz-border-image: url(imago_tesla/BarraBordeMenuDespTreat.png) 6 6 5 2 stretch; 
    -webkit-border-image: url(imago_tesla/BarraBordeMenuDespTreat.png) 6 6 5 2 stretch; 
    -o-border-image: url(imago_tesla/BarraBordeMenuDespTreat.png) 6 6 5 2 stretch; 
    border-image: url(imago_tesla/BarraBordeMenuDespTreat.png) 6 6 5 2 fill stretch;
}
#than {
    margin-left:0.70em;
}

header nav ul li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;

    top:0.001em;
    height:100%;
    margin-right:1em;

    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
header nav ul li a {
    font-family:sans-serif, helvetica, arial;
    font-weight:450;
    font-size:1rem;
    color:#000;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin: auto 0;
}
header nav ul li ul{
    background-color:#fff;

    overflow:show;
    width:150px;
    height:80px;

}
header nav ul li ul li{
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin: auto 0;
    height:17px;
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
}
header nav ul li ul li a{
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin: auto 0;
    display:block;
    bottom:15px;
    font-weight:900;
}
.menuHead ul {
  -webkit-transition:1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:1s ease-in-out;
  transition:1s ease-in-out;
  border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
  left:2em;
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:12;
  top:1em;
  transition:1s ease-in-out;
  visibility:hidden;
}
.menuHead:hover > ul, .menuSub1:hover > ul {
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
}
/*-----MAIN-----*/
#main {
    width:99.5%;
    margin:auto;

    left:50em;

    overflow:hidden;
}

/*Slideshow*/
#main #slideshow {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    height:45em;
    position:relative;
}
#main #slideshow .thumb {
    width:75%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#main #slideshow article {
    float:left;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1rem;
    text-align:justify;
    width:25%;
    color:#FF00FF;
    background-color:rgb(119, 141, 0);
    color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#main #slideshow article p{
    margin-left:1%;
    width:98%;
    position:relative;
}
#main #slideshow article h2 {
    font-weight:300em;
    text-align:left;
    font: bold 30px/1.1em "Chelsea Market";
}
#main #slideshow article h2 a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:1%;
    width:98%;
}

#main #slideshow article .date {
    font-family:sans-serif, helvetica, arial;
    font-size:.8rem;
    font-weight:500em;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    color:#777777;
}
#main #slideshow .slidesjs-pagination li {
    background:#fff;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin-right:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#main #slideshow .slidesjs-pagination li a {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
    font-size:0pt;
}
#main #slideshow .slidesjs-pagination li .active {
    background:#333333;
}
```

And this is the 3/3 jqwdinka.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //initial
  $('#content').load('main.php');
  $('body').load().css('background-image', 'url(' + 'imago_tesla/fondo0.jpg' + ')');


  //handle menu clicks
  $('ul#cont li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(page + '.php');

    var pageImages = {
      'main': 'imago_tesla/fondo0.jpg',
      'verduras': 'imago_tesla/fondo4.jpg',
      'Frutas': 'imago_tesla/fondo4.jpg',
      'MoteconHuesillo': 'imago_tesla/fondo4.jpg',
      'ComoComprar': 'imago_tesla/fondo2.jpg',
      'Contacto': 'imago_tesla/fondo.jpg'
    }

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + pageImages[page] + ')');
  });
});
```

That would be

Any comment, suggestion, Question for improve the question or any kind of answer that can be directly or indirectly helpfull would be much apreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is going straight to my favorites :D

Comment: Post a fiddle, Or share live website link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `position:Absolute;` applied on the body in your CSS. 
It is removing the whole page from the normal flow.